# Linux Deepin language switcher - making it smoother like in Ubuntu

Tags: locale, desktop-environment, deepin

I installed the latest Linux Deepin 2014.2 distro. It's a Chinese distro based on Ubuntu 14.04.

The OS is great, but there's one annoying flaw - when switching language, there appears a transparent switcher, and you need to switch **again** to actually make the change happen. It looks like this:

[image]

I'd like to have something similar to Ubuntu's behavior (switches immediately)

Comment: what? nobody? nothing?

Comment: Never even heard of it...  Anyway, does CCSM work on your distro? (I'm using boring Vanilla Ubuntu myself, so there might be some back-and-forth going on)

Comment: @Fabby Deepin uses GO as a backend, building their UI as HTML5 applications. As such, they have some weird stuff going on there. My last experience (with their previous release) tells me CCSM might screw things up a lot. I prefer a more direct approach (i.e doing things manually), if you can help with that :-)

Comment: Sorry Yuvi, no clue even where to start to look...  :(

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems absent in later versions of Deepin Linux.